# How to self-host a WCF REST XML Service over https without using app.config?

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, rest, c#-4.0

My service works fine over http using the following code:

```
WebServiceHost serviceHost = new WebServiceHost(typeof(RestInterface), new Uri(http://localhost/rest));
serviceHost.Open();
```

When I try to host the exact same service over https it doesn't work.  I get nothing in Service Trace Viewer and Chrome just says "This web page is not available".  Here is the code I use for https:

```
var serviceHost = new WebServiceHost(typeof(RestInterface), new Uri(https://localhost/rest));

serviceHost.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode =
    X509CertificateValidationMode.Custom;

serviceHost.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.CustomCertificateValidator =
    new CertValidator(); // Custom validator that will accept any cert

serviceHost.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(
    StoreLocation.LocalMachine,
    StoreName.My,
    X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,
    "localhost");

var binding = new WebHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport;

var ep = serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IRestInterface), binding, "");
ep.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());

serviceHost.Open();
```

Has anyone gotten this working?  What am I doing wrong?!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured it out.  I need to bind the cert to the port.  Don't do:

```
serviceHost.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode =
    X509CertificateValidationMode.Custom;

serviceHost.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.CustomCertificateValidator =
    new CertValidator(); // Custom validator that will accept any cert

serviceHost.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(
    StoreLocation.LocalMachine,
    StoreName.My,
    X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,
    "localhost");
```

instead do:

```
Process bindPortToCertificate = new Process();
bindPortToCertificate.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.SystemX86), "netsh.exe");
bindPortToCertificate.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:{0} certhash={1} appid={{{2}}}", epAddress.Port, cert.Thumbprint, Guid.NewGuid());
bindPortToCertificate.Start();
bindPortToCertificate.WaitForExit();
```

Taken from:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/james_osbornes_blog/archive/2010/12/10/selfhosting-a-wcf-service-over-https.aspx

Here is my working code.  It still needs to be cleaned up a bit:

```
WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(RestInterface));

X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
var cert = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "localhost", false)[0];
store.Close();


Process bindPortToCertificate = new Process();
bindPortToCertificate.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.SystemX86), "netsh.exe");
bindPortToCertificate.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:{0} certhash={1} appid={{{2}}}", epAddress.Port, cert.Thumbprint, Guid.NewGuid());
bindPortToCertificate.Start();
bindPortToCertificate.WaitForExit();

var ep = serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IRestInterface), binding, epAddress);
ep.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
serviceHost.Open();
```

Comment: Nice, this works. However I still get a trust error (DLG_FLAGS_INVALID_CA): "Your PC doesn’t trust this website’s security certificate." Is there an easy solution for this?